# Pass gpg key password when signing a release

Tags: gnupg, kubernetes-helm

I use a gpg key that is secured with a password.
Is there a way to pass the password to the underlying gpg command?

```
helm package --sign \
--key "my_key_name" \
--version "$VERSION" \
--app-version "$APP_VERSION" \
--keyring ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg my-chart
```

I tried echoing the password and piping it, also tried the `yes` command, but that does not seem to work.

When I do `echo "password" | helm package ...` I get `Error: inappropriate ioctl for device`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [helm](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/provenance.md) documentation:

> NOTE: If your PGP private key has a passphrase, you will be prompted
>   to enter that passphrase for any commands that support the --sign
>   option. You can set the HELM_KEY_PASSPHRASE environment variable to
>   that passphrase in case you don't want to be prompted to enter the
>   passphrase.

The final command is:

```
export HELM_KEY_PASSPHRASE=<password>
helm package --sign \
--key "my_key_name" \
--version "$VERSION" \
--app-version "$APP_VERSION" \
--keyring ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg my-chart
```

Comment: Do you know which release this will be included in? Right now I see it's been merged to master, but the latest version (2.11) doest not seem to include the change.

Comment: Yes, it was recently added to `master`. I suppose, it will be added in `2.12.0`.

Comment: Does anyone guide me on how `secring.gpg` would work , I seem to have issue exporting private key.